# 0 != 9 and 0 != 10 in Python?

Tags: python, output

I need to write a function that computes the number of integers from start to finish (excluding the last) with a while loop. I keep getting an output of 0 != 9 and 0 != 10. 
Code:

```python
n = 0
k = 1

def div_3_5(start, end):
    global n
    return n
    while (n<k):
        print("Divisible by 3 or 5") 
        if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0:
            n +=1
```

I've been stuck on this for some time now, could someone please help

Comment: You never actually go into the while loop as you return before it... You want to do the work, and then at the *end* of the function, `return n`...

Comment: I tried that, and the output then becomes return outside of function, or it outputs that I shouldnt ask for a return inside the loop.  restructuring my code has been a bit of an issue..

Comment: Sounds like you're moving it outside of the `def`... move it to the bottom of the funciton, but at the same level as the `while`... so it's  still indented a level within the `def`...

Comment: It simply outputs "You probably don't want a return statement inside the while loop"

Comment: The level you've got your `return n` - just put it after the entire **`while` block**... not inside the `while` statement itself... eg: the same level it's at now but at the *end* of the function itself...

Comment: Understood, but it still gives the same output, i.e, 0 != 9 and 0 != 10

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do... what are `n` and `k` used for... how are you calling your `div_3_5` function... what are `start` and `end` supposed to be used for - they're not mentioned inside `div_3_5` itself... what's your ultimate aim here?

Comment: I'm trying to write a function that computes the number of integers from start up to, but not including end that are divisible by 3 or 5 using a while loop. n represents the first integers, k the last integer.

Comment: Are you aware of Python's builtin `range` function which you can loop over...

Comment: Somewhat, how would I set it up?

Comment: I'd suggest you spend some time reading a Python tutorial and learning bits step by step... You're missing many key concepts necessary for what you're trying to do here. I'm afraid SO isn't here for teaching/hand-holding every little thing

Comment: No dramas, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have the return n statement almost on top of your function, with result the program to never execute your loop

```py
n = 0
k = 5

def div_3_5(start, end):
   flag = False
   number = start
   count = 0
   while flag is False:
      if number % 3 == 0 or number % 5 == 0:
         print("Divisible by 3 or 5")
         print(number)
         count += 1  # So you can see how many times the condition is met

      if number == end:
         flag = True

      number += 1
   print(count)
   return count

div_3_5(n, k)
```

Comment: I moved it in the same position, but it still outputs the 0!= 9 and 0!= 10 error

Comment: No that's all the code, i'm doing it in an online quiz format, and so it's testing whether it computes the number of integers from start to finish (excluding end) divisible by 3 or 5

Comment: Ok, you need a for loop, because with that condition while loop will keep looping because the conditions will never met. Also you don't need global variable(n) and you should avoid global variables in general.

Comment: I would but this quiz requires you to use a while loop, and I only included that global n because otherwise it outputs local variable 'n' referenced before assignment.

Comment: Ok, let me make some changes

Comment: @JohnFoggo this is the right way to do it with a while loop